# How to do bitwise ANDING in c using just ~ and |

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I need to make a function using just `~` and `|`,
such that function `f(6, 5)` will return `4` as the answer.

Comment: Google for the Morgan Laws

Comment: Rather De Morgan's Laws

Comment: yup just did, understood THANKS !!

Comment: To those voting to close as "too localized": I don't see how this is not a general programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By De Morgan's law, `~(a | b)` equals `~a & ~b`. By the same law, `a & b` equals `~(~a | ~b)`.

Answer (score 1):

~(~a|~b)

Interpretation:

~a : bits which are 0 in a

~b : bits which are 0 in b

~a|~b: bits which are 0 in either a or b

~ of ~a|~b: bits which are not 0 in either a or b, that is they are 1 in both

Answer (score 1):

```
int f(int a, int b)
{
    return ~(~a|~b);
}
```

[De Morgan's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws%E2%80%8E)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

so the below line will help you to achieve adding using negation and bitwise OR

~(~a | ~b)